# how can I output something to the SSMS "Messages" tab from an SSMS add-in

Tags: ssms-addin, ssms-2014

I'm working on an SSMS 2014 addin, and I need to output stuff to the messages tab of the active document.

I know I can get that document like this :

```
var document = ((DTE2)ServiceCache.ExtensibilityModel).ActiveDocument;
```

but I've not been able to figure how to access its Messages tab (nor its Results tab for that matter)

Of course, as usual with SSMS Addins, there's no documentation.

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution?